# Imperative + and, or Imperative + then

Tags: grammar, imperatives

Imperative + and, or Imperative + then. Which one is more correct?

Does anyone know? please answer me.

Study hard, and you will become a great teacher.
Study hard, then you will become a great teacher.

Answer (score 1):

*Study hard,  and ( then) you will become a great teacher* is the correct sentence.

You can use then [then](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Then) with the following meaning:

> In that case; accordingly: If traffic is heavy, then allow extra time.
>
> Next in time, space, or order; immediately afterward: watched the late movie and then went to bed.

- If you study hard, then you'll be come a great teacher. ( your second option with the omission of ' if you').
- Study hard, *and then* you'll become a great teacher.